# Gensim 3.4.0 word2vec unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim

I have changed the code in word2vec.py to this:

```
\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py in reset_weights(self, hs, negative, wv)
   1417         for i in xrange(len(wv.vocab)):
   1418             # construct deterministic seed from word AND seed argument
-> 1419             wv.vectors[i] = self.seeded_vector( "".join(str(wv.index2word[i]),str(self.seed)), wv.vector_size)
   1420         if hs:
   1421             self.syn1 = zeros((len(wv.vocab), self.layer1_size), dtype=REAL)
```

But I receive the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

On line 1419, where the arrow is pointed. I don't understand how the operand is concatenating an int and str when both are within a str() method?

I am using Anaconda environment if thats matters in python3

Comment: Have you tried debugging into `self.seeded_vector` to see what is happening "under the hood"?

Comment: Yes, it did not help, though I think I found the issue (somewhat), I was processing in binary files to feed the model and some characters weren't parsing correctly which was causing it to fail.